# Unresponsive iMessages and FaceTime on Mojave

Tags: macos, messages, mojave, facetime

I have this issue with Messages, FaceTime when it gets unresponsive on start. Same issue was with Contacts, but following some recommendations on the web i've reset the Contacts database and it works now. But with messages/facetime no luck, tried many solutions, resetting nvram/pram, deleting configs and databases, etc.

Is there a way to reinstall iMessages and FaceTime completely?

Comment: Have you tried a clean install of the OS? I think those packages can only be reinstalled with the complete system.

Comment: Well, i'm sure clean install is likely to fix it, but i don't want to overwrite my data/settings for other apps (

Comment: Something like that happened to me long time ago and I just backed up my settings on iCloud and made a clean install. Maybe if you reinstall but not clean install just the OS it can fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried deleting files in the ~/Library/ folder? ('~/' means your user folder)
search facetime there, try deleting what you find.
It might sign you out, at the same time it might solve your problem.
You can search 'Messages' there as well.

I don't guarantee it won't do any harm. Yet it's what I usually do when I run into problems. It's sort of DIY mentality.

If you don't see the Library folder, it's because it's hidden by default.
You can change that in "Show View Options" menu in "View" option of Finder. Or by pressing command and j at the same time. (You should be at ~/ for this option to be shown).

Comment: Deleting random .plist files without any background information or specific information can be hazardous to the health of the OP’s system.

Comment: I second what @IconDaemon says.  Indiscriminately deleting files you don't know what its indented function is, is foolhardy and no way to diagnose/repair issues.  DIY doesn't mean to blindly hammer away until you hit a nail - it means you're *doing it yourself.*   I don't down vote often, but this one earned it.

Comment: I've deleted sqlite databases but not plists, that does seem fishy

Comment: Hammering works when a system is designed stupidly complex.

Your downvoting means a lot to me.